# How to pass an array in multiple view in laravel 5.7?

Tags: php, laravel

I am asking some thing in laravel  such that 
   How to be pass an array which are get from database  to the multiple views ? 
    I am using this code

```
return View::make('products.manage-category',$arrCategoryData)->nest('products.add-category',$arrCategoryData);
```

But this code produce an error.

[image]

Comment: View composers is what you need https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/views#view-composers

Comment: Please never share error messages in images!

Comment: ^ Take a screenshot. I personally use https://gyazo.com/